# ImageView not displaying image located at URL

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

My Android application has five names to select from. The user can click on one of them and a new activity will open to display a photo of that person (taken from a URL). All five images are practically identical: .jpg, about the same dimensions, etc. The first two images load in fine, the third and fourth don't show up at all, and the fifth works fine too.

I printed and tested the URLs for the images not showing up so I know that's not the issue. I see `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` in the logs. Searching around SO, I found suggestions to call `reset()` on the input stream to fix this issue. However, I tried this and my app crashed.

I've been stuck on this bug for hours so any suggestions are greatly appreciated. The code I'm using to fetch the images is below. Also, not sure if it's worth mentioning, but the broken images are consistently missing across different emulators and my tablet.

```
class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

        private String url;
        private ImageView imageView;

        public ImageLoadTask(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            this.url = url;
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                return myBitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Input your image urls into browser's, could they be displayed?

Comment: @SilentKnight yup, the image urls are perfectly fine

Comment: I tried your code and used 4 images and they are working just fine.
Can you post the URLs of the images you are using?

Answer (score 0):

see this tutorial about theming list view (like facebook news feeds) it contains the part that display images from the web in the listview items .. its a great tutorial it will help you .. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/
you can download and edit the source code